# If statements to check every permutation

Tags: database, c#-2.0

Hi I am trying to evaluate a list of 3 data records coming back from database.

I need to check if these values are null & replace with a "-" symbol.

The problem I end up is having a very long list of if statements, is there an easy way to do this?

```
if (row count == 1)
{
    if (only firstNull)
    {
        //Replace first.label with "-"
    }
    else if (only secondNull)
    {
        //Replace second.label with "-"
    }
    else if (only thirdNull)
    {
        //Replace third.label with "-"
    }
    else if (only (firstNull && secondNull))
    {
        //Replace first.label = "-" & second.label = ""
    } 
    else if (only (secondNull && thirdNull))
    {
        //Replace second & third label = "-"
    }
    else if (only (thirdNull && firstNull))
    {
        //Replace third && first label = "-"
    }
}
else
{
    // Replace all labels with "-"
}
```

Comment: there might be foreach loop!!try that

Answer (score 1):

When you access the specified fields you can use the nullable operator:
`field ?? "-"`. This will yield the field name or `"-"` if `field==null`.

for example

```
Object field = null;
System.Console.WriteLine(field ?? "field is null");
```

will output:

> field is null

without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have so many clauses...  If a field is null, you want to replace it with "-"... You have 3 fields, you should at most have 3 clauses...  (Note, this is pseudocode, to match your question)

```
if (row count == 1)
{
    if (firstNull)
    {
        //Replace first.label with "-"
    }
    if (secondNull)
    {
        //Replace second.label with "-"
    }
    if (thirdNull)
    {
        //Replace third.label with "-"
    }
}
else
{
    // Replace all labels with "-"
}
```

You don't need to handle every combination of the 3 fields as separate ifs...

Ideally your fields would be stored in some kind of collection (which you've omitted), that way you would be able to do something like:

```
if(row count == 1)
{
    foreach(field in Fields) 
    {
        if(fieldIsNull) 
        {
            // Set corresponding label to "-"
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside, if you always want to do a translation when reading from the database, so that if it is NULL, you want '-', then it may make sense to handle this as part of your select clause.  So, with Oracle you could have:

```
SELECT
    NVL(FIELD1, '-'),
    NVL(FIELD2, '-'),
    NVL(FIELD3, '-')
FROM
    SOME_TABLE
```

I think for SQLServer, the equivalent would be:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(FIELD1, '-'),
    ISNULL(FIELD2, '-'),
    ISNULL(FIELD3, '-')
FROM
    SOME_TABLE
```

Both of these would mean that the database returned '-' instead of NULL if the column was empty.  This does of course assume that the column you're returning is a string type.  If not, you would have to perform the appropriate conversion on the field to turn it into one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to go through each record and check whether they are null. If the record you are looking at is null, replace it with "-".